# MS-Teams apps, accessing native device capabilities

Tags: reactjs, microsoft-teams, microsoft-teams-js, msteams-react-base-component

I'm using the below approach to access the camera & gallery from an MSTeams app.

Link: [Access device permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/device-capabilities/native-device-permissions?tabs=mobile%2Cteamsjs-v2%2Cmobile1#manage-permissions)

I'm facing 2 errors,
**Error 1:** 1000App doesn't have sufficient permission to use this API
This is when i dont use "navigator.permissions.query({ name: 'camera' });"
If i use the above navigator permission to prompt the permission alert i get the 2nd warning/exception ie
**Error 2:** Exception Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'query')

Can some please help..!

Comment: Above error has been fixed in sample by moving that code into separate JS and calling that JS function wherever needed. https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/blob/main/samples/tab-device-permissions/nodejs/src/NavigatorPermission.js

Can you please check this out once.

Comment: @Meghana-MSFT No luck.. I'm still facing the same issue.
FYI, Mine is a **javascriprt tab app**(not typescript). Do you have any working sample..?

Comment: Can you please let us know how and from where you are calling navigator.permissions.query({ name: "camera" })? Currently we do not have a working sample in Javascript for device permissions.

Comment: @Meghana-MSFT I have created a navigatorPermisson.js likewise u suggested and calling in my javascript(jsx)

Comment: Can you please share your complete javascript code base repo at microsoftteamsdev@microsoft.com